# Ao chamar uma página com Redirect está dando erro

Tags: c#

Esse é o erro que está dando:

```
Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.
```

E esse é o código de chamada completo em minha master.

```
protected void lkbConsultarProcessos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            try
            { 
                Response.Redirect("/frmPVListaProcessos.aspx");
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                wucMasterMensagens.ExibirMensagem(WUC.wucMensagens.TipoAlerta.Erro, Ex.Source, Ex.Message, Ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Request.Redirect(url, false);
```

Utiliza o valor false no parâmetro endResponse!

Comment: O erro não deu mais, mas a página solicitada não é carregada. Isso vou ver o que está acontecendo.